# Security issues in PHP/Sql

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

I'm a beginner. I wrote this and I have been told my find() method had security vulnerabilty. I thougt that the if else of my queryType method prevented from Sql injections attempts.

```
    public function queryType(string $sql, array $attributes = null)
    {
        ## instance of Database singleton
        $this->Database = Database::getInstance();

        if($attributes !== null) {
            ## if attr, prepared request
            $query = $this->Database->prepare($sql);
            $query->execute($attributes);
            return $query;
        }else{
            ## else, simple request
            return $this->Database->query($sql);
        }
    }

    ## SECURITY ISSUE /!\ ?? queryType if/else doesn't prevent ??

    public function find(int $id)
    {
        return $this->queryType("SELECT * FROM {$this->table} WHERE id = $id")->fetch();
    }
```

How can I solve it ?

Comment: your `queryType` method is, this allows a raw query to be executed in there, and your `find` doesn't utilize placeholders, albeit with a type hint, it's not being used properly. and be careful with `{$this->table}`, if this is user supplied, you'll need to whitelist it with your tables or just define this

Answer (score 5):

Code only provides security if you actually use it. Because you're not passing any parameters, the query shown will fall into the "else, simple request" case, so the fact that `queryType` *supports* parameters is irrelevant. It's like fitting a heavy iron bolt to your door, but never sliding it into place - it won't keep anyone out.

In this case, `$id` is guaranteed to be an int, so the risk is minimal, but you should get in the habit of [**always** using parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/157957): `$this->queryType("SELECT * FROM {$this->table} WHERE id = ?", [$id])`

However, you have another dynamic part which [can't be a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/182287/157957): `$this->table` If there is any way for the user to choose that value, it would be a huge security vulnerability. If this is for some kind of "ORM" where you have a class for each table, it would probably be sensible to use a class constant instead (e.g. `$tableName = static::TABLE_NAME;`); that way, sub-classes can define a value, but it will never be calculated at run-time, so you can't accidentally put a user-controlled value into it.

Comment: I've written elsewhere that frameworks protect against SQL injection like a toothbrush protects against dental cavities.